# Excel - See if cells in one column contain text from another

Tags: excel, search, contains, lookup

Currently I am using the below to see if cells in column B exist in Column A...

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B1,A:A,0)),"False","True")
```

... However I've just realised the need to not check for an exact match, but rather if the cells in column B contain text that appear in any of the cells in column A.

For example, if a cell in column B contains "TIC081_CL1" then I could return "true" if column A contains a cell with only "TIC081"...

Can anyone help me with this please, as my current working only works for eact matches. Many thanks for any assistance!!!

Comment: If a cell in A only contained lets say `TIC` or even just `T` should it still return true?

Comment: Ah good point! No, but I think in my case it's pretty certain that in every instance there may just be a suffix of underscore and something "_XXXX". But the first bit is of no fixed character length, neither is the suffix. But more than likely there will be an underscore seperating the two.

Comment: I suggest you to add a new column with `Find` function then check a `COUNTIF` over that new column ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is guaranteed that there will be an underscore "`_`" separating the values you are searching for we only need to check 2 distinct conditions:

1. If the entire value B1 is found within A:A
2. If the value before the `_` is found within A:A

We can accomplish that by using an additional `MATCH` derived from your original formula:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(MID(B1,1,FIND("_",B1)-1),A:A,0)),IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B1,A:A,0)),"False","True"),"True")
```

You can alternatively do this using 2 `COUNTIF` formulas:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,B1)+COUNTIF(A:A,MID(B1,1,FIND("_",B1)-1))>0,"True","False")
```

Comment: Works brilliantly... Thank you very much!!